# laravel 5.4 add new element to basecontroller array

Tags: php, constructor, global-variables, laravel-5.4, breadcrumbs

i have a question about dynamic breadcrumbs in laravel 5.4 . i don't want use package for this so my question is that:

i write a basecontroller like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    private $breadcrumbs;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->breadcrumbs[] = [
            'title' => 'Home',
            'type' => 'route',
            'href' => 'admin.dashboard'
        ];

        view()->share('breadcrumbs', $this->breadcrumbs);
    }
}
```

and i use it in child controller like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Management;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BaseController;

class PackageController extends BaseController
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        $this->breadcrumbs[] = [
            'title' => 'Packages',
            'type' => 'route',
            'href' => 'admin.package.list',
            'class' => 'active'
        ];

        return view('admin.layouts.package.list');
    }
```

i want use this breadcrumbs variable in breadcrumbs.blade.php partial in master page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    @include('admin.layouts.shared.breadcrumb')
</body>
</html>
```

breadcrumbs partial view renders an ul list has multiple li>a tags.
but this is not working now.

1 . why it doesn't work ?

2 . how can add a new breadcrumb array element to breadcrumb variable in basecontroller and render full parts with added last element ?

please help me ?

( sorry my bad english )

Answer (score 1):

The parent constructor runs *before* the `getList()` function. This means that the following has already run:

```
view()->share('breadcrumbs', $this->breadcrumbs);
```

I'm pretty sure it makes a copy of the breadcrumbs array when you share it, not leaving a reference to it so you can modify it as you go.

Why not make a method in the base controller like:

```
public function setBreadcrumbs($breadcrumbs)
{
    $this->breadcrumbs = $breadcrumbs;
    view()->share('breadcrumbs', $this->breadcrumbs);
}
```

And then in `getList()` call it like this:

```
$this->setBreadcrumbs([
    'title' => 'Packages',
    'type' => 'route',
    'href' => 'admin.package.list',
    'class' => 'active'
]);
```